# Check SharePoint group membership using many sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I know it is wrong, but our SharePoint designed to use so many SharePoint sites instead of using subsites. Each site has it's own groups. Access granted on each sites by SP groups, not by AD groups. How should I check the user which SP groups belongs to?

For example

User is member of group called "Company" on a site A. Also member of a group called "Marketing" on Site B. We have 100+ sites and many groups for each sites (not necessary with the same names). I would like to know which groups the user belongs to without checking all sites one by one

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using PowerShell script.

For example[(original article](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/permission-report-for-specific-user.html#ixzz2macjy36a)):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Function GetUserAccessReport($WebAppURL, $SearchUser, [Switch]$verbos){
    [Integer]$writeHostPrefixCount = 0
    [String]$writeHostPrefixType = "  "
    #Output Report location
    $OutputReport = ".\UserAccessReport.csv"

    #delete the file, If already exist!
    if (Test-Path $OutputReport) {
        Remove-Item $OutputReport
    }

    if($verbos){ Write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Scanning Farm Administrator Group..." }

    #Write CSV- TAB Separated File) Header
    "URL`tSite/List`tTitle`t PermissionType`tPermissions" | out-file $OutputReport

    ####Check Whether the Search Users is a Farm Administrator ###
    #Get the SharePoint Central Administration site
    $AdminWebApp= Get-SPwebapplication -includecentraladministration | ? {
        $_.IsAdministrationWebApplication
    }

    $AdminSite = Get-SPweb $AdminWebApp.Url
    $AdminGroupName = $AdminSite.AssociatedOwnerGroup
    $FarmAdminGroup = $AdminSite.SiteGroups[$AdminGroupName]

    #enumerate in farm adminidtrators groups
    foreach ($user in $FarmAdminGroup.users) {
        if($user.LoginName -eq $SearchUser) {
            "$($AdminWebApp.URL)`tFarm`t$($AdminSite.Title)`t Farm Administrator`tFarm Administrator" | Out-File $OutputReport -Append
        }    
    }

    ### Check Web Application Policies ###
    if($verbos){ Write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Scanning Web Application Policies..." }
    $WebApp= Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL

    foreach ($Policy in $WebApp.Policies) {
        #Check if the search users is member of the group
        if($Policy.UserName -eq $SearchUser) {
            [Integer]$writeHostPrefixCount = 1
            if($verbos){ Write-Host $($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)$Policy.UserName -ForegroundColor Red }
            $PolicyRoles=@()
            foreach($Role in $Policy.PolicyRoleBindings) {
                $PolicyRoles+= $Role.Name +";"
            }
            if($verbos){ Write-Host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Permissions: " $PolicyRoles -ForegroundColor Red }
            "$($AdminWebApp.URL)`tWeb Application`t$($AdminSite.Title)`t  Web Application Policy`t$($PolicyRoles)" | Out-File $OutputReport -Append
        }
    }

    [Integer]$writeHostPrefixCount = 0
    if($verbos){ Write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Scanning Site Collections..." }
    #Get All Site Collections of the WebApp
    $SiteCollections = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $WebAppURL -Limit All

    #Loop through all site collections
    foreach ($Site in $SiteCollections) {
        [Integer]$writeHostPrefixCount = 1
        if($verbos){ Write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Scanning Site Collection:" $site.Url }
        #Check Whether the Search User is a Site Collection Administrator
        foreach ($SiteCollAdmin in $Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators) {
            if($SiteCollAdmin.LoginName -eq $SearchUser) {
                "$($Site.RootWeb.Url)`tSite`t$($Site.RootWeb.Title)`t Site Collection Administrator`tSite Collection Administrator" | Out-File $OutputReport -Append
            }    
        }

        #Loop throuh all Sub Sites
        foreach ($Web in $Site.AllWebs) {
            [Integer]$writeHostPrefixCount = 2
            if($Web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True) {
                if($verbos){ Write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Scanning Site:" $Web.Url }

                #Get all the users granted permissions to the list
                foreach($WebRoleAssignment in $Web.RoleAssignments ) {
                    [Integer]$writeHostPrefixCount = 3
                    #Is it a User Account?
                    if($WebRoleAssignment.Member.userlogin) {
                        #Is the current user is the user we search for?
                        if($WebRoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq $SearchUser) {
                            if($verbos){ Write-Host  $($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)$SearchUser has direct permissions to site $Web.Url -ForegroundColor Red }
                            #Get the Permissions assigned to user
                            $WebUserPermissions=@()
                            foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $WebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings) {
                                $WebUserPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                            }
                            if($verbos){ write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)with these permissions: " $WebUserPermissions -ForegroundColor Red }

                            #Send the Data to Log file
                            "$($Web.Url)`tSite`t$($Web.Title)`t Direct Permission`t$($WebUserPermissions)" | Out-File $OutputReport -Append
                        }
                    }
                    #Its a SharePoint Group, So search inside the group and check if the user is member of that group
                    else {
                        foreach($user in $WebRoleAssignment.member.users) {
                            #Check if the search users is member of the group
                            if($user.LoginName -eq $SearchUser) {
                                if($verbos){ Write-Host  "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)$SearchUser is Member of " $WebRoleAssignment.Member.Name "Group" -ForegroundColor Red }
                                #Get the Group's Permissions on site
                                $WebGroupPermissions=@()
                                foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $WebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings) {
                                    $WebGroupPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                }
                                if($verbos){ write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Group has these permissions: " $WebGroupPermissions -ForegroundColor Red }

                                #Send the Data to Log file
                                "$($Web.Url)`tSite`t$($Web.Title)`t Member of $($WebRoleAssignment.Member.Name) Group`t$($WebGroupPermissions)" | Out-File $OutputReport -Append
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ###*****  Check Lists with Unique Permissions *******###
            foreach($List in $Web.lists) {
                [Integer]$writeHostPrefixCount = 3
                if($List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True -and ($List.Hidden -eq $false)) {
                    if($verbos){ Write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Scanning List:" $List.RootFolder.Url }
                    #Get all the users granted permissions to the list
                    foreach($ListRoleAssignment in $List.RoleAssignments ) {
                        [Integer]$writeHostPrefixCount = 4
                        #Is it a User Account?
                        if($ListRoleAssignment.Member.userlogin) {
                            #Is the current user is the user we search for?
                            if($ListRoleAssignment.Member.LoginName -eq $SearchUser) {
                                if($verbos){ Write-Host  $($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)$SearchUser has direct permissions to List ($List.ParentWeb.Url)/($List.RootFolder.Url) -ForegroundColor Red }
                                #Get the Permissions assigned to user
                                $ListUserPermissions=@()
                                foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $ListRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings) {
                                    $ListUserPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                }
                                if($verbos){ write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)with these permissions: " $ListUserPermissions -ForegroundColor Red }

                                #Send the Data to Log file
                            "$($List.ParentWeb.Url)/$($List.RootFolder.Url)`tList`t$($List.Title)`t Direct Permissions`t$($ListUserPermissions)" | Out-File $OutputReport -Append
                            }
                        }
                        #Its a SharePoint Group, So search inside the group and check if the user is member of that group
                        else {
                            foreach($user in $ListRoleAssignment.member.users) {
                                if($user.LoginName -eq $SearchUser) {
                                    if($verbos){ Write-Host  "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)$SearchUser is Member of " $ListRoleAssignment.Member.Name "Group" -ForegroundColor Red }
                                    #Get the Group's Permissions on site
                                $ListGroupPermissions=@()
                                    foreach ($RoleDefinition  in $ListRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings) {
                                        $ListGroupPermissions += $RoleDefinition.Name +";"
                                    }
                                    if($verbos){ write-host "$($writeHostPrefixType*$writeHostPrefixCount)Group has these permissions: " $ListGroupPermissions -ForegroundColor Red }

                                    #Send the Data to Log file
                                "$($Web.Url)`tSite`t$($List.Title)`t Member of $($ListRoleAssignment.Member.Name) Group`t$($ListGroupPermissions)" | Out-File $OutputReport -Append
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Write-host "`n Access Rights Report Generated!" -ForegroundColor Green
}


#Call the function to Check User Access
GetUserAccessReport "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" "i:0#.w|Global\Salaudeen"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PowerShell script below:

```
$sites = Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet.contoso.com | Get-SPSite -limit all
"Site Collection`t Group`t User Name`t User Login" | out-file groupmembersreport.csv
foreach($site in $sites)
{
    $sitegroup = $site.RootWeb.SiteGroups |?{$_.Name -EQ "Power Users"}
    foreach($user in $sitegroup.Users)
        {   
        "$($site.url) `t $($sitegroup.Name) `t $($user.displayname) `t $($user) " | out-file groupmembersreport.csv -append
        }
$site.Dispose()
}
```

More information check the article:

[PowerShell Script – list all SharePoint group members](http://sharepointchips.com/2016/03/powershell-script-query-sharepoint-group-members/)